# Configuration Dask Distributed

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm setting up an environment for our data scientists to work on. Currently we have a single node running Jupyterhub with Anaconda and Dask installed. (2 sockets with 6 cores and 2 threads per core with 140 gb ram). When users create a LocalCluster, currently the default settings are to take all the available cores and memory (as far as I can tell). This is okay when done explicitly, but I want the standard LocalCluster to use less than this. Because almost everything we do is

Now when looking into the config I see no configuration dealing with n_workers, n_threads_per_worker, n_cores etc. For memory, in `dask.config.get('distributed.worker')` I see two memory related options (`memory` and `memory-limit`) both specifying the behaviour listed here: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html.

I've also looked at the jupyterlab dask extension, which lets me do all this. However, I can't force people to use jupyterlab.

TL;DR I want to be able set the following standard configuration when creating a cluster:

1. n_workers
2. processes = False (I think?)
3. threads_per_worker
4. memory_limit either per worker, or for the cluster. I know this can only be a soft limit.

Any suggestions for configuration is also very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-09-20 this isn't implemented.  I recommend raising an feature request at https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new , or even a pull request.